# getJSON requests returns Uncaught Reference & SyntaxError

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm using the getJSON function to capture contents returned from a URL call, however, I keep running into error Reference or Syntax errors.

If I run the script getUserAgentDetails() with "agent_name" as the parameter, I receive the uncaught ReferenceError, stating Chome (the browser I'm using) is not defined, whereas, if I use the parameters "agent_version" or "os_name" I receive the uncaught Syntax error, stating unexpected number.

I believe the unexpected number from "os_name" is due to the '7' in my Windows 7 operating system, so I suspect the contents are not being handled correctly when returned.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getUserAgentDetails(param) {
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON(('http://www.useragentstring.com/?uas=' + encodeURI(navigator.userAgent) + '&getText=' + param + '&callback=?'), function(data) {
    var parts = data.split('=');
    alert(parts[1]);
  });
});
}

getUserAgentDetails("agent_name"); //Results in "Uncaught ReferenceError: Chrome is not defined"
//getUserAgentDetails("agent_version"); //Results in "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number "
//getUserAgentDetails("os_name"); //results in "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number "
</script>
```

Comment: You can't use this service with javascript, it's restricted by same origin policy.

Comment: Can you explain why? I thought appending "&callback=?" resolved the same origin issue?  Also, do you have suggestions for an alternate approach?

Comment: when the server doesn't respond with jsonp (and he does not) there is no way. You must search for a service that supports jsonP, or do the parsing of the UA-string on your own.

Answer (score 0):

For request such as cross domain requests i.e; in your case **json** will not work..
You need to used **jsonp** in such cases..

Check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP)

Comment: I tried using JSONP in the following approach, but am still hitting the same errors.  Suggestions? 
`function getUserAgentDetails2(param) {
 $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: ('http://www.useragentstring.com/?uas=' + encodeURI(navigator.userAgent) + '&getText=' + param),
  async: false,
  jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data)
  {
   var parts = data.split('=');
   $('test').value=parts[1];
  }
 });
}

getUserAgentDetails2("agent_name");` Sorry about the horrible formatting